# FirebaseCrashlytics crash does not report crash while creating build from Appcenter

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase-crash-reporting

When I install build from Xcode its reporting crash properly but when I try to create build from Appcenter same crash is not reported.

I am checking with release mode. I have tried both Workspace-settings i.e. **New build system** and **Legacy Build System** but no luck.

Using XCode 11.2.1 & FirebaseCrashlytics(~> 4.0.0) pod.

Answer (score 1):

Check for Enable Bitcode settings for all third-party frameworks. If all are bitcode enable then set Bitcode to Yes otherwise set to NO

In Build Settings >> Build Options >> Enable Bitcode set value for Project and Targets 
Also check for Bitcode in Pod project if you are using Cocoapods.